# Not able to capture the malformed or corrupted records while using com.crealytics.spark.excel library in pyspark

Tags: excel, apache-spark, pyspark

I have an excel file which is having many columns including a date field but some of the records are not having proper date values which is having slash(/) or 00/00. So I want to capture those malformed records becuase of incorrect date values.

Below is my code snippet in pyspark. I have kept the actual column names hidden and given some dummy names.

```
sheet_name = "'Sheet1'!A1"

file_name = "Test.xlsx"
s3_file ="s3://my_bucket/xcel_file/Test.xlsx"

schema1 = StructType([
            StructField("a", IntegerType(), True),
            StructField("b", StringType(), True),
            StructField("c", DateType(), True), 
            StructField("corrupted", StringType(), True)
            ])

df = spark.read.format("com.crealytics.spark.excel") \
                    .option("dataAddress", sheet_name) \
                    .option("header", "true") \
                    .option("inferSchema", True) \
                    .option("dateFormat", "MM/dd/yy") \
                    .option("parseMode", "PERMISSIVE") \
                    .option("keepUndefinedRows", True) \
                    .option("useNullForErrorCells", True) \
                    .option("treatEmptyValuesAsNulls", True) \
                    .option("columnNameOfCorruptRecord", 'corrupted') \
                    .option("setErrorCellsToFallbackValues", "true") \
                    .schema(schema1) \
                    .load(s3_file)*
```

While I am displaying the data fame I am getting the error as **NoSuchElementException: key not found: corrupted.** I am not sure whats the wrong i am doing here. Can someone help on this. I am using databricks run time 10.3 which uses spark 3.2.1 and scala 2.12. This is the library I am using com.crealytics:spark-excel_2.12:3.2.1_0.16.5-pre1 for excel file read.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9841Q.png)

Comment: Use substitute() to replace the / with a colon or whatever needed.

Comment: @SolarMike I am not clear what you say. Can you please elaborate how to do. Because the corrupted records are not showing in the data frame itself.

Comment: substitute() is a function in excel.

Comment: @SolarMike I do not want to edit the excel file. Every time we get a new excel file though the schema is same.

Comment: Oh, you tagged excel, so it seemed to be an option.